# Python dictionary program output issue

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am done working on a practice program. It prints very well but the issue is that the last three lines of the output are inaccurate. Each time I run the program it generates different outputs, alternates between the keys. I am not able to find a way to have it come out right (as written in the program)

```
def main( ):
    zip_dictionary = {}
    zip_dictionary = update_dictionary(zip_dictionary, "CAM", "1427")
    zip_dictionary = update_dictionary(zip_dictionary, "UofM", "1427")
    zip_dictionary = update_dictionary(zip_dictionary, "ZIT", "1423-503")
    zip_dictionary = update_dictionary(zip_dictionary, "MCOC", "1423")
    zip_dictionary = update_dictionary(zip_dictionary, "NAZARETH", "1418")
    zip_dictionary = update_dictionary(zip_dictionary, "OCC", "1420")

    for key in zip_dictionary:
        print(key, zip_dictionary[key])

    for i in range(2):
        print(zip_dictionary.popitem( ))

    for value in zip_dictionary:
        print(zip_dictionary[value], key)

def update_dictionary(dct, key, value):
    dct[key] = value
    return dct
main( )
```

Comment: Dictionaries are *unordered*. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your last `for` loop looks strange to me. Did you intend to use `key` there? Because the value of `key` won't change as you iterate through `value`. It will continually point to the last value that `key` had from the first for loop.

Comment: Please **edit the question**, allowing you to format that readably. Also, what you expected to get instead would probably help.

Comment: Your code looks over-complicated, why don't you "update" the dictionary by adding key-value pairs directly instead of calling a function every time? This is really not efficient and also harder to read and understand. If you need the order of elements retained, use `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: My expectation is to have the zip code match the location. for example the problem here is OCC will be printed 4 times with the wrongs zip. and if I run it again CAM will be printed in the for last lines with the wrongs zip. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Again: **Edit. The. Question.**

Comment: @Kevin it does kinda make sense. What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an OrderedDict, don't bother with `update_dictionary`, and don't print `key` while you're iterating over `value`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def main( ):
    zip_dictionary = OrderedDict()
    zip_dictionary["CAM"] = "1427"
    zip_dictionary["UofM"] = "1427"
    zip_dictionary["ZIT"] = "1423-503"
    zip_dictionary["MCOC"] = "1423"
    zip_dictionary["NAZARETH"] = "1418"
    zip_dictionary["OCC"] = "1420"

    print "\nContents of dict:"
    for key in zip_dictionary:
        print(key, zip_dictionary[key])

    print "\nPopping items:"
    for i in range(2):
        print(zip_dictionary.popitem( ))

    print "\nRemaining items:"
    for key in zip_dictionary:
        print(key, zip_dictionary[key])

main( )
```

Result:

```
Contents of dict:
('CAM', '1427')
('UofM', '1427')
('ZIT', '1423-503')
('MCOC', '1423')
('NAZARETH', '1418')
('OCC', '1420')

Popping items:
('OCC', '1420')
('NAZARETH', '1418')

Remaining items:
('CAM', '1427')
('UofM', '1427')
('ZIT', '1423-503')
('MCOC', '1423')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get 'the same' output every time you can sort the keys first based on alphabetical order.

```
for sorted_key in [key in zip_dictionary].sort():
    print(sorted_key , zip_dictionary[sorted_key])
```

If they *need* to be in that order, you could also maintain an ordered list with keys. You also don't need to return the dictionary in the `update_dictionary` function due to it being a mutable object.

```
def update_dictionary(dct, lst, key, value):
    dct[key] = value
    if not key in lst:
        lst.append(key)

def main( ):
    zip_dictionary = {}
    zip_list = []
    update_dictionary(zip_dictionary, zip_list, "CAM", "1427")
    update_dictionary(zip_dictionary, zip_list, "UofM", "1427")
    update_dictionary(zip_dictionary, zip_list, "ZIT", "1423-503")
    update_dictionary(zip_dictionary, zip_list, "MCOC", "1423")
    update_dictionary(zip_dictionary, zip_list, "NAZARETH", "1418")
    update_dictionary(zip_dictionary, zip_list, "OCC", "1420")

    for key in zip_list:
        print(key, zip_dictionary[key])
```